# Iam not able see the vertices when dragged it down

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, filmic-blender, blender-osm

[image]

File Link:
--> [image]

I am a beginner at blender, I trying to do a donut which I saw on YouTube(blender guru).

I dragged the vertices down and then I saved(not sure) it. I am not able to see the dragged vertices, dear Blender community help me with his

Comment: I don't know how you dragged them exactly, but obivously you cannot see them because they are inside the other mesh. So it looks as if you not just dragged them down but inwards as well. Now you have to drag them out again.

Comment: Press Z > Wireframe to see the wires. Press Alt-Z to see through geometry. That way you can select the vertices easily.

Comment: it looks like your vertices are just behind the faces of the donut, you have enabled the Snap option so they should stick to the surface but maybe you haven't followed the instructions correctly, hard to say, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots I updated the question along with the file. Review it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertices of the icing are behind the faces of the donut. To fix that enable the *Face Project* option of the *Snap*:

[image]

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to see the vertices, select them, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to exit transparency, move the vertices, they will stick the faces of the donut, and back to *Object* mode:

[image]